# Get method's instance owner

Tags: javascript, oop

Given a class and an instance of it

```
var class=function() {
    this.propA=99;
    this.methodA=function() {
        console.log(this.propA);
    };
};

var object=new Class();
```

I'd like to be able to perform a call to methodA where `this` will be the instance of it and the example (`this.propA`) will work. Exactly as

```
object.methodA.call(object);
```

*but* without having any reference to `object`. Like this in some pseoducode:

```
var methodToCall=object.methodA;
...
...
methodToCall.call(getInstanceOwnerOf(methodToCall));
```

The objective of this is to pass methods as callbacks to async functions and keep `this` as the instance when the method is called.

Some workarounds would be to pass `method` and `object` to that async function,  or to store `this` in a local variable, but these are the things I want to avoid.

Comment: Functions don't have an "owner". There's no inherent meaning or significance to the fact that a function is associated with an object property. You can use `.bind()` (on the Function prototype) to *create* a function with a fixed `this` binding.

Answer (score 2):

Use bind to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the context you want function called in. Note this returns a NEW function which is not the same as the original.

I usually create the new function and give it a different name but you can do it multiple ways.

To be more specific, you can't be sure [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the class the function is declared in, depends on how you called the function and if you are in strict mode.

an example below:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7af535L/

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(someVar) {
    this.myVar = someVar;
    this.publicSayVar = this.sayVar.bind(this);
  }

  sayVar() {
    console.log(this.myVar);
  }


}

var object = new SomeClass("hello");
var testcall = object.publicSayVar;
testcall();
```